# Is there a simple Javascript library or script to handle simple logic tests?

Tags: javascript, parsing, logic

I've been tasked with making a number of options on our website depend on a pre-requisite of completed tasks.

Right now I store objects with a string prerequisite. Eg:

```
Task1 = {...};
Task2 = {preq:'Task1', ...}
```

So I can easily check that Task2 is only available when Task1 is complete.

The problem is that the tasks are becoming more complicated and I need to allow for AND / OR logic. Ideally I'd be able to use an expression such as

```
Task4 = {prereq:'(Task1&Task2)|Task3}, ...}
```

which would make task4 available if either task 1 and 2 has been completed OR task 3 has been completed.

I'm not really sure about the best way to go about this. I feel that maybe I need a parser or something similar so I'd appreciate a solution or at the very least pointers in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Right now, I'm using a system similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/jEzaz/

I want to be able to potentially use a range of AND and OR conditions. Right now, I'm just being asked to allow more than one which is easy enough (eg. completing task1 or task2 means you can now do task3) - but I can see the need for more versatility in the future.

I hope that all makes sense!

Comment: You could use a score system ... each task would have a score and you would have to check for a minimum score value.

Comment: you can try use some data structure instead of string

Comment: how you want use this?

Comment: I've updated with my question with a jsFidlle - I hope that's clearer. Even with using objects - I still need to work out how best to resolve the AND / OR conditions.

Comment: You may consider looking at [machina-js](http://machina-js.org/) It's a finite state machine with a lot of flexibility. I'm pretty sure you can do what you want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple parser to convert a string prerequisites to a function returning true/false. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/a9F6Z/

```
var Task = (function() {
    //string to function converter
    var parse = function(str) {
        str = "return " + str.replace(/\|/g, '||')
                .replace(/&/g, '&&')
                .replace(/(\w+\d+)/g, function($1) {
                    return 'all["' + $1 + '"].done';
                });
        return new Function("all", str);        
    },
        returnTrue = function() {
            return true;
        }, 
        all = {};
    /**
     * Task constructor
     */
    function Task(params) {
        this.name = params.name;
        //task is available by default
        this.prereq = params.prereq ? parse(params.prereq) : returnTrue;
        //task is not done.
        this.done = false;
        //register a task.
        Task.all[this.name] = this;
    };

    /**
     * All tasks map storage.
     */
    Task.all = all;

    /**
     * Make a task complete
     */
    Task.prototype.complete = function() {
        this.done = true;
    };

    /**
     * Make a task incomplete.
     */
    Task.prototype.reopen = function() {
        this.done = false;
    };

    /**
     * Check if task is available due to prerequsites.
     */
    Task.prototype.isAvailable = function() {
        return this.prereq(all);  
    };

    return Task;
}());
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks! It seems so simple in some aspects.

Answer (score 2):

for a sample you can try using next structure and function for checking

if no prerequisites will be set null
if one - will be set string name
if several with or - will be use object `{or: ["task1","task2"...]}`
if several with and - will be use object `{and: ["task1","task2"...]}`

also for combine - will be use object like `{and: [{or:["task1","task2"]},"task3",{or:{"task5"...}}]}`

so sample tasks list may be like this

```
var myObj = {
    task1: {name: 'Hello', prereq:null, selected: false},
    task2: {name: 'World', prereq:'task1', selected: false},
    task3: {name: 'Foo', prereq:{or:["task4","task2"]}, selected: false},
    task4: {name: 'Bar', prereq:null, selected: false},
    task5: {name: 'Baz', prereq:{and:[{or: ["task4","task6"]},"task1"]}, selected: false},
    task6: {name: 'Barrr', prereq:null, selected: false}
};
```

for checking use function like

```
function preq(arr,config){
    if(!config) return true;
    if(typeof config === "string") return arr[config].selected;
    if('or' in config){
        for(var i=0,L=config['or'].length;i<L;i++){
            if(preq(arr,config['or'][i])) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if('and' in config){
        for(var i=0,L=config['and'].length;i<L;i++){
            if(!preq(arr,config['and'][i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

also you can check sample in work on [JSFiiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEzaz/8/)

Comment: That works really nicely as well - but the Yury's simple parser solution seems to be an easier implementation in this instance.

Comment: @JohnReid yep, you right :-)